# Why does my R Shiny app throw MIME errors inconsistently?

Tags: r, shiny, mime, shinyapps

I have an app deployed on shinyapps.io. Most of the time it works without an issue. However, at seemingly random times the app will disconnect. I believe the image attached below, with several MIME errors, shows the error that is occurring each time the app disconnects ("Refused to apply style from '' because its MIME type ('text/html') is not a supported stylesheet MIME type, and strict MIME checking is enabled).

My question is why does this happen only sometimes? Is there a way to prevent this? It seems like the files throwing errors are housed in libraries that I'm using; I've updated all of my packages, so I don't think anything should be deprecated on my end. I know assistance can be minimal without a MWE, but I'm not allowed to share the full link or source. Any ideas/guidance would be greatly appreciated.

[image: javascript console MIME errors]